# Find column headers and highlight it including below cells of it

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim headersRange As Range, cellsToloop As Range
Dim col As Long, lRow As Long, colName As String

Set headersRange = Range("HeadersToFind")

For Each cellsToloop In headersRange 'This line works
  If cellsToloop.Value = "Sun" Then 'This line works
    cellsToloop.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 100) ' up to here

    'From here it does nothing
    col = cellsToloop.Column
    colName = Split(col.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)
    lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(colName & "8:" & colName & lRow)
    rng.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)
    'Upt her doesnt work
  End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

With this code, i managed to highlight the headers but i failed to highlight cell under each column header Sun.

Comment: Is this code even running? I dont see a With, so this line `lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should error out.

Comment: you are using the `.` in front of your ranges, but have no `With` block to state the parent.  Either add the `with` block or remove the `.` at the beginning and it will refer to the active sheet.

Comment: Also look into `Cells()` as it will take a number instead of a letter for the column reference.

Comment: No erros!!! Its quiet. Thanks for reply!

Comment: your picture does not show any values.  Your line `lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` finds the last row in that column with values which is the column header.  So It will not color anything.  If your columns do not have any values you will need to hard code the last row or base it on Column A that has the "Total", `lRow = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1`

Comment: If anyone to assist me, please take the code, refer to picture and rewrite the code as i spent 3 weeks trying to rewrite the code!!! That is why i posted the question. Amen

Comment: That is not what this site is for, we are here to help **YOU** overcome the problem not do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim headersRange As Range, totalCell As Range, sunCell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set headersRange = Range("HeadersToFind")

    With headersRange
        Set totalCell = .Cells(1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1)
        Set sunCell = .Find("Sun", , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not sunCell Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = sunCell.Address
            Do
                .Parent.Range(sunCell, .Parent.Cells(totalCell.Row, sunCell.Column)).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)
                Set sunCell = .FindNext(sunCell)
            Loop While sunCell.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

where I assumed that:

- table is always empty at the moment the macro runs
- "total" is always in `headersRange` first column

should they not be true the code can be easily adapted

Comment: @MdugoTrading, did you get through it?

Comment: Ohhhh!!! Jesus Christ!!!... Simple as that? Thanks user3598756... You are so Genius... Although it highlights up to the end of worksheet cells but it works and i will try to work on it to highlight to the last Border cell. Thank You. Unfortunatle i was able to mark only one answer, But Both codes does it perfectly!!! Powerful Guys!!! Amen

Comment: it highlights "up to the end of worksheet" or "down" to it?

Comment: It Highlight up to Raw 1048576 Last Row of Worksheet instead of the last row of my bordered cells above the Total row. Refere to the picture

Comment: My code assumes that 1) there's a cell with "total" below the first cell of `headersRange` 2) there's no data below `headresRng`. Which is exactly what I could see in your picture. Does it still hold true?

Comment: Sorry Man!!! I was going through all the codes!!! and your comments!!! but ive just finnished now, since have Internet access here at work. You are so Genius!!! It works 100000% I rectified my mistake again. I didnt realise that i deleted Total by mistake. I put it back and it Works!!!  I realy love you!!! God Bless You!!!

Comment: Yaaaa!!! i can see Set totalCell = .Cells(1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1) is setting up to the last row where String is Total -1 in the first column. Oooh!!!

Comment: it was just to put things clear, since you already had an accepted answer. good coding!

Comment: Ok!!! if i Set firstAddress = Range(sunCell).Offset(1, 0).Address, Can this assign to the cell underneath the header if i want to highlight the cell below only? When i Test it nothing happens

Comment: in this latter case just substitute `.Parent.Range(sunCell, .Parent.Cells(totalCell.Row, sunCell.Column)).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)` with `sunCell.Offset(1).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)`

Comment: Powerful!!! sunCell.Offset(1).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200) fills the first cells underneath the columns, But what i did is Modified .Parent.Range(sunCell, .Parent.Cells(totalCell.Row, sunCell.Column)).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200) TO .Parent.Range(sunCell.Offset(1), .Parent.Cells(totalCell.Row, sunCell.Column)).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200) to highlight all underneath headers!!! of which is your exact code inside parent looping range!!! Anyway I realy love your code. Now am going to do anything i want like Performing Calculations with this code!!! powerful!!! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your code is not throwing any error then definitely something wrong with your Excel/VBE.

It should throw error at :

`colName = Split(col.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)` because col is declared as long hence should have no .cells property.

`lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
`Set rng = .Range(colName & "8:" & colName & lRow)`
 because to use `.Range` you need a With Clause.

---

This should be the correct code to fill all the `Sun` columns with a color.

```
Sub test()

    Dim headersRange As Range, cellsToloop As Range
    Dim rngFind As Range


    '/ Sheet1 is just an example name.
    Set headersRange = Sheet1.Range("HeadersToFind")

    '/ To Fill upto a specific value in a cell
    Set rngFind = Sheet1.Cells.Find("Total", , , xlWhole)

    For Each cellsToloop In headersRange
        If cellsToloop.Value = "Sun" Then
            '/ Fill all the way to last cell
            Sheet1.Range(cellsToloop, cellsToloop.End(xlDown)).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)

            '/ Fill all they way upto usedrange's lastrow.
            cellsToloop.Resize(Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)

            '/ To Fill upto a specific value in a cell
            If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
             cellsToloop.Resize(rngFind.Row, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(160, 160, 200)
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Ohhhh!!! Jesus Christ!!!... Simple as that? Thanks cyboashu... You are so Genius... Although it highlights up to the end of worksheet cells but it works and i will try to work on it to highlight to the last Border cell. Thank You

Comment: Ok!! I have taken a look at this code.  You have done it 3 ways, meaning First line code it loops to end of the worksheet row as you specified, then used range and to specific range. Thanks again. It works perfectly, i can see my mistakes very well...